# Embed video into 'AxesSubplot' on jupyter / ipython notebook

Tags: python, video, matplotlib, mp4, jupyter

I'm trying to embed a video into a [jupyter / ipython notebook](http://jupyter.org/) cell.

The following instructions work perfectly (as you can see in the picture below) if you want the video to be played as the output of the cell:

```
import io
import base64
from IPython.display import HTML

#video = io.open('/home/ubuntu/Downloads/test.mp4', 'r+b').read()
encoded = base64.b64encode(video)

HTML(data='''<video alt="test" controls>
     <source src="data:video/mp4;base64,{0}" type="video/mp4" />
     </video>'''.format(encoded.decode('ascii')))
```

[image]

However I'm trying to create a cell output with 4 [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) axis in which 2 of them are regular plots and 2 of them are embedded videos.

Using this command I create a grid of subplots:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(10,10),sharex=False,sharey=False)
```

and then I can plot on each one of them by individually indexing it and plotting, i.e.:

```
ax[0][0].plot([x_1, x_2], [y_1, y_2], 'bo-', linewidth=4)
```

**How do I embed the HTML into one of the axis?**

I naively tried with:

```
ax[0][1].HTML(data='''<video alt="test" controls>
     <source src="data:video/mp4;base64,{0}" type="video/mp4" />
     </video>'''.format(encoded.decode('ascii')))
```

but obviously got the following error since there is no HTML attribute for the axes subplot:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-a3bc39226382> in <module>()
      7 
      8 fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(10,10),sharex=False,sharey=False)
----> 9 ax[0][1].HTML(data='''<video alt="test" controls>
     10                 <source src="data:video/mp4;base64,{0}" type="video/mp4" />
     11              </video>'''.format(encoded.decode('ascii')))

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'HTML'
```

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot do that.

Comment: @cel - could you please detail a bit more?

Comment: You could create a hardcopy of the images and then create an HTML table where you can embed the images and the videos using HTML code. As @cel said, I think it is not possible to do what you want in the way you are trying.